# How to prevent data from being written into a directory?

Tags: filesystem, security, directory

Or: How to make a directory write protected, for all users until unlocked again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use (1)

```
chmod a-w directory
```

which will make the directory unwritable to everyone.

To give write access to all users:

```
chmod a+w directory
```

For more fine access, there is a [nice tutorial on Unix permissions here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm); if you need even more fine-grained control, you can use [Access Control Lists](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) (this last link is for Arch Linux, but works on Ubuntu too).

---

*Footnotes*:

(1) this is if you are the owner of the directory and you have write access on the parent directory. Otherwise, you have to do it with superuser privileges, like:

```
sudo chmod a-w directory
```

and

```
sudo chmod a+w directory
```

Comment: Thanks! I was still in my windows mindset, where permissions and write protection are different things.